# attaching click event to childnode doesnt work but directly to the ID does work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dilemma when I try to target a particular element through accessing child nodes click event will not work but if I use getElementById then attach it through that it will work butI need to ideally do it through child nodes. below is my code.

```
jQuery('#begin_consult').click(function(){
  jQuery('.cq-container').show();
  jQuery('#begin_consult').hide();
  if(jQuery('.option').hasClass('c_questions')){
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName('c_questions');
        for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
            jQuery('.main-body').append(y[i].innerHTML);

           var get_age_gparent = document.getElementsByClassName('age-check')[0];
           get_age_gparent.style = "display:block;";
           var get_age_parent = get_age_gparent.childNodes[1];
           var getOptionsDD = get_age_parent.childNodes[3];
           var getOptionsUL = getOptionsDD.childNodes[1];
           var getInputNo = getOptionsUL.childNodes[1];
           var getRadioBtnAge = getInputNo.childNodes[0];
           getRadioBtnAge.onclick = function(){
            alert('fffff');
        };
    }

 }

});
```

Comment: You know you can just do `$('.c_questions').on('click', ...`

Comment: I can't do that...  the class age-check gets attached way up the dom tree I'm trying to add an event handler to an input radio button and I don't want to get the input by ID because I need to repeat this code for several products

Comment: Seems that you need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), as you are creating elements dynamically using `append()`

Comment: Why mix DOM and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use another approach.  Your current implementation makes your code strictly dependent on the structure of your HTML.  If you ever change even the slightest item, it will break.  you add an image, an icon, or wrap an element in a div.
If i was you, i would reference them in a different manner.
Sudo code i have not tested or ran:

```
var get_age_gparent = jQuery('.age-check').first();
get_age_gparent.css({'display':'block'});
var get_age_parent = get_age_gparent.find('.ageparent');//add new class on target
var getOptionsDD = get_age_parent.find('.optionsdd');//add new class on target
var getOptionsUL = getOptionsDD.find('.optionsUL');//add new class on target
var getInputNo = getOptionsUL.find('.inputNo');//add new class on target
var getRadioBtnAge = getInputNo.find('input[type=radio].btnage');//add btnage classname to target button
getRadioBtnAge.click(function(){
alert('fffff');
});
```